# Find level of binary tree with randomly generated numbers inserted c++

Tags: c++, binary-tree

This code runs fine without errors, but I can not figure out how to get the level of the binary tree without knowing the actual numbers of each node. I currently have a for loop which I know is not correct, but I don't know how to find out the level of the binary tree. I also want to see if I can find out all nodes that have one child.

```
#ifndef BINARYTREE_H
#define BINARYTREE_H

class BinaryTree
{
private:
    struct TreeNode
    {
        int value;        
        TreeNode *left;    
        TreeNode *right;   
    }; TreeNode *root;       


    void insert(TreeNode *&, TreeNode *&);
    void destroySubTree(TreeNode *);
    void deleteNode(int, TreeNode *&);
    void makeDeletion(TreeNode *&);
    void displayInOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPreOrder(TreeNode *) const;
    void displayPostOrder(TreeNode *) const;

public:
    // Constructor
    BinaryTree()
    {
        root = nullptr;
    }

    // Destructor
    ~BinaryTree()
    {
        destroySubTree(root);
    }

    // Binary tree operations
    void insertNode(int);
    bool searchNode(int);
    void remove(int);

    void displayInOrder() const
    {
        displayInOrder(root);
    }

    void displayPreOrder() const
    {
        displayPreOrder(root);
    }

    void displayPostOrder() const
    {
        displayPostOrder(root);
    }
    int countNodes(TreeNode *);
    void count();
    int getLevelTree(TreeNode *, int, int);
    int getLevel(int);
};
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;

// insert accepts a TreeNode pointer and a pointer to a node. The function inserts the node into 
// the tree pointed to by the TreeNode pointer. This function is called recursively. 
void BinaryTree::insert(TreeNode *&nodePtr, TreeNode *&newNode)
{
    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        nodePtr = newNode;                  // Insert the node.
    else if (newNode->value < nodePtr->value)
        insert(nodePtr->left, newNode);     // Search the left branch
    else
        insert(nodePtr->right, newNode);    // Search the right branch
}


// insertNode creates a new node to hold num as its value, and passes it to the insert function. 
void BinaryTree::insertNode(int num)
{
    TreeNode *newNode;      // Pointer to a new node.

                            // Create a new node and store num in it.
    newNode = new TreeNode;
    newNode->value = num;
    newNode->left = newNode->right = NULL;

    // Insert the node.
    insert(root, newNode);
}


// destroySubTree is called by the destructor. It deletes all nodes in the tree.   
void BinaryTree::destroySubTree(TreeNode *nodePtr)
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        if (nodePtr->left)
            destroySubTree(nodePtr->left);
        if (nodePtr->right)
            destroySubTree(nodePtr->right);
        delete nodePtr;
    }
}


// searchNode determines if a value is present in the tree. 
// If so, the function returns true. Otherwise, it returns false.  
bool BinaryTree::searchNode(int num)
{
    TreeNode *nodePtr = root;

    while (nodePtr)
    {
        if (nodePtr->value == num)
            return true;
        else if (num < nodePtr->value)
            nodePtr = nodePtr->left;
        else
            nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
    }
    return false;
}


// remove calls deleteNode to delete the node whose value member is the same as num.
void BinaryTree::remove(int num)
{
    deleteNode(num, root);
}


// deleteNode deletes the node whose value member is the same as num.
void BinaryTree::deleteNode(int num, TreeNode *&nodePtr)
{
    if (num < nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(num, nodePtr->left);
    else if (num > nodePtr->value)
        deleteNode(num, nodePtr->right);
    else
        makeDeletion(nodePtr);
}


// makeDeletion takes a reference to a pointer to the node that is to be deleted. 
// The node is removed and the branches of the tree below the node are reattached. 
void BinaryTree::makeDeletion(TreeNode *&nodePtr)
{
    // Define a temporary pointer to use in reattaching
    // the left subtree.
    TreeNode *tempNodePtr;

    if (nodePtr == NULL)
        cout << "Cannot delete empty node.\n";
    else if (nodePtr->right == NULL)
    {
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->left;   // Reattach the left child
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
    else if (nodePtr->left == NULL)
    {
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;  // Reattach the right child
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
    // If the node has two children.
    else
    {
        // Move one node the right.
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr->right;
        // Go to the end left node.
        while (tempNodePtr->left)
            tempNodePtr = tempNodePtr->left;
        // Reattach the left subtree.
        tempNodePtr->left = nodePtr->left;
        tempNodePtr = nodePtr;
        // Reattach the right subtree.
        nodePtr = nodePtr->right;
        delete tempNodePtr;
    }
}


// The displayInOrder member function displays the values 
// in the subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via inorder traversal. 
void BinaryTree::displayInOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->left);
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        displayInOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}


// The displayPreOrder member function displays the values  
// in the subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via preorder traversal. 
void BinaryTree::displayPreOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
        displayPreOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayPreOrder(nodePtr->right);
    }
}


// The displayPostOrder member function displays the values 
// in the subtree pointed to by nodePtr, via postorder traversal.
void BinaryTree::displayPostOrder(TreeNode *nodePtr) const
{
    if (nodePtr)
    {
        displayPostOrder(nodePtr->left);
        displayPostOrder(nodePtr->right);
        cout << nodePtr->value << endl;
    }
}
int BinaryTree::getLevelTree(TreeNode *node, int val, int lev)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (node->value == val)
    {
        return lev;
    }
    int downlev = getLevelTree(node->left, val, lev + 1);
    return downlev;
}
int BinaryTree::getLevel(int val)
{
    return getLevelTree(root, val, 1);
}

int BinaryTree::countNodes(TreeNode *root)
{

    if (root == NULL)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        int count = 1;
        count += countNodes(root->left);
        count += countNodes(root->right);
        return count;
    }

}
void BinaryTree::count()
{
    cout<< countNodes(root);
}

#include <iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<numeric>
#include<ctime>
#include "BinaryTree.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int randNum;
    vector<int> randData;
    vector<int>::iterator iter;
    size_t size = randData.size();
    srand(time(0));
    BinaryTree tree;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        randNum = rand() % 1000 + 1;
        tree.insertNode(randNum);

    }
    cout << "display : \n";
    tree.displayInOrder();
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=5;i++)
    { 
        cout<< "getlevel: "<<tree.getLevel(i);  
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wait. Are you *sure* you're tasked with writing a member that, given a root and a value, returns the *level* that value resides on ? That would entail *finding* the node, which you can do without less-greater comparison, using only equivalence (albeit inefficiently) by enumerating exhaustively, but you're left with the possible state where the value is *not* in the tree, and in that case, what are you expecting as a result? In short, your problem needs clarification.

Comment: @WhozCraig I don't need my function arguments to be root and value, but I assumed it would be easier to return the level. However, Since all the numbers are randomly generated I figured out the way I coded my function is not a solution. I need to _ count and print the level of the tree_. My binary tree works fine, I just need to find the level of the tree and print it. Finding a node as you said doesn't seem like a solution but I might be wrong. Since, I'd have to know all the randomly generated values, in this case I only have 5 but if I have 50 values then it becomes a problem.

Comment: the level of any tree, rooted at some non-null pointer p, is conceptually simple: Given a function `level(node *p)` with the default case of `p==null` returning `0`, the calculation is simply: `1 + max(level(p->left), level(p->right))`. Every data structures text I've seen touches (briefly) on this algorithm. Is that what you're looking for ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, I think that is what I am looking for. I tried it out and it seems to work as expected. Thank You